# how to get store configurations from cache in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1, cache

I'm trying to find out the way to get store configuration values (`Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $store)`) from cache. 
The reason for this is that I don't want to make db connections every time I'm calling the configuration values. 
Is there a way to use cache for the said purpose?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Mage::getStoreConfig` automatically uses Magento cache.

It uses the `getConfig` method from `Mage_Core_Model_Store` which as you can see return the value from the cache if set:

```
public function getConfig($path)
{
    if (isset($this->_configCache[$path])) {
        return $this->_configCache[$path];
    }

    $config = Mage::getConfig();

    $fullPath = 'stores/' . $this->getCode() . '/' . $path;
    $data = $config->getNode($fullPath);
    if (!$data && !Mage::isInstalled()) {
        $data = $config->getNode('default/' . $path);
    }
    if (!$data) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->_processConfigValue($fullPath, $path, $data);
}
```

The `$_configCache` is initiated via the `initConfigCache` method from `Mage_Core_Model_App` which is itself called during the `_initStores` method. If we continue, the `_initStores` method is called during the `_initCurrentStore`, itself called when `Mage::run` is called.

Answer (score 3):

`Mage::getStoreConfig($path,$store)` is already stored in cache if you look in this file `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`

```
protected function _initModules()
{
    if (!$this->_config->loadModulesCache()) {
        $this->_config->loadModules();
        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded() && !$this->_shouldSkipProcessModulesUpdates()) {
            Varien_Profiler::start('mage::app::init::apply_db_schema_updates');
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates();
            Varien_Profiler::stop('mage::app::init::apply_db_schema_updates');
        }
        $this->_config->loadDb();
        $this->_config->saveCache();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

To verify if values coming from cache, change value direct from db table `core_config_data` you will see the result